# When a town is upgraded to a city, do football clubs in that town change their names?

Tags: football

Is there precedent for, or have there been any examples of, what a football team does if their name contains the type of settlement they represent and then the settlement is granted city status?

For example, if Huddersfield became a city, could we guess what Huddersfield Town might do about their name, if anything, based on what any other team in a similar position has done previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best example here is almost certainly [Swansea City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swansea_City_A.F.C.), who were founded as Swansea Town in 1912, but then did change to the Swansea City name in 1969 as Swansea was upgraded to a city.

[Chelmsford City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelmsford_City_F.C.) would seem to be a good candidate here, but for reasons unexplained in the Wikipedia page, they formed as Chelmsford City in 1938, 74 years before Chelmsford acquired city status in 2012. Weird.